# Nvidia GTX 780 cable installation

Tags: graphics-card, motherboard, power-supply

I have researched online but I am  not confident in how I should connect of my GFX to PSU and MB. I have checked the manual which came with the PSU and the manual which came with the case, none of these have any information.

1 x Corsair AX760i PSU
2 x Nvidia 780GTX Classified GFX.

Each GFX card simply slots into the motherboard, on the top of each GFX card I have two 6 pin connections, one 5 pin connection and one slim long connection.
Each card came with 2 single 8 pin cables, which I assume plug into the two 8 pin slots on the single card, however each of these cables branch out into two 6 pin connections themselves, so after all is connected, each card has 2 cables leading out of it with four 6 pin connections. As I have two of these GFX cards this is a total of 8 open 6 pin connections.

Am I really supposed to plug 8 of these connectors into the PSU? My PSU only has six 6 pin slots on the back.

Update : Here are the cables which came with the GFX cards.
[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Directly from the [EVGA website](http://www.evga.com/Products/Product.aspx?pn=03G-P4-3788-KR) we have this little snippet:

> **Requirements**
> Minimum of a 600 Watt power supply.
> (Minimum recommended power supply with +12 Volt current rating of 42 Amps.)
>
> Two available 8-pin PCI-E power connectors or four available 6 pin PCI-E power connectors
>
> Total Power Draw : 250 Watts

That makes it pretty clear that you do infact need to use:

Four 6 pin connectors per graphics card.

**OR**

Two 8 pin connectors per graphics card.

The good news is that you should be able to use some of the 8 pin PCI-e connectors on your power supply, and you should have received enough modular cables with your power supply to connect everything you need.

[image: Corsair AX760i PSU]

Comment: Thanks, As the information is so small I probably overlooked it in the manual(if its inside that is).

Comment: I don't think they even supply a GTX780 specific manual. Normally it's just a general installation guide.

Comment: Yes, it is very basic, I haven't brought any PC part for a long time, years ago you would get detailed instructions containing numbered parts and how they are assembled, not anymore.